# How do I read values > 1 from a MySql TinyInt(1) column using .Net EF?

Tags: .net, mysql, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am supplementing an open source web application with additional .net powered reports. In the database, there is a column that is a TinyInt(1), which is presumed by Entity Framework to be a boolean.

The issue I found was that the application is using the column as an enumeration with values of 2 or higher in there as well. Unfortunately I can't change the schema of this application.

Attempting to set the framework to map the column to SByte instead of boolean caused a compile error, and Google and Stack searches haven't been successful yet.

Before I write a custom class with manual SQL rolled in it to fetch these values, is there a way to convince EF to treat the column as anything other than bool?

Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

tinyint(1) is an 8bit value, but restricted to 1 character display (the `(1)`). older versions of mysql didn't support boolean fields, so tinyint(1) was traditionally used to simulate them. remove the display size restriction and it should be treated as any other 1byte int.

Comment: Hello Marc - thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately I can't alter the database schema, as much as I would like to. I will remember this for my own DB design going forward though, so thank you for the information.

Comment: it's not really altering the schema. it'll still be a tinyint, you'll just have removed the display hint, allowing more than 1 character to show through.